# I'm getting a syntax error when trying to create this function in snowflake

Tags: function, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_AAR.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime (dateTime TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), shiftCalendarID int)

RETURNS int
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$

DECLARE
        time time:=TIME(:dateTime);
        curDay  int;
        prvDay  int;
        shiftID int;
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
        :shiftCalendarID = ID,
         curDay := DATEDIFF( day, BeginDate, :dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1,
         prvDay := ( :curDay + PeriodInDays - 2 ) % PeriodInDays + 1
    FROM DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_AAR.ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = :shiftCalendarID
        OR (    :shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= :dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC;
    
    RETURN shiftID;
    END;
$$
```

The error i'm getting is 'syntax error line 7 at position 5 unexpected 'curDay'. (line 7)'. maybe i'm declaring it wrong. but not sure how i'm supposed to declare it. for reference, here is the working function in SQL Server.

I tried using "let" after each variable, but that didnt work, i even tried getting rid of time variable but same issue came up with curDay.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime] (
       @dateTime datetime,
       @shiftCalendarID int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @time    time = CONVERT( time, @dateTime ),
        @curDay  int,
        @prvDay  int,
        @shiftID int;

    SELECT TOP 1
        @shiftCalendarID = ID,
        @curDay = DATEDIFF( dd, BeginDate, @dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1,
        @prvDay = ( @curDay + PeriodInDays - 2 )       % PeriodInDays + 1
    FROM ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = @shiftCalendarID
        OR (    @shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= @dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC;

    SELECT @shiftID = ID
    FROM Shift
    WHERE ShiftCalendarID = @shiftCalendarID
        AND (  ( FromDay = @curDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= @time         AND TillTimeOfDay >  @time )
            OR ( FromDay = @curDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= @time )
            OR ( FromDay = @prvDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND TillTimeOfDay >  @time )
        );

    RETURN @shiftID;
END 
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

the [SELECT INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/into.html) form is required thus the first block should be:

```
    SELECT TOP 1
        ID,
        DATEDIFF( day, BeginDate, :dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1,
        ( :curDay + PeriodInDays - 2 ) % PeriodInDays + 1
        INTO :shiftCalendarID, :curDay, :prvDay
    FROM ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = :shiftCalendarID
        OR (    :shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= :dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC;
```

and the second block would be like:

```
    SELECT ID into :shiftID
    FROM Shift
    WHERE ShiftCalendarID = @shiftCalendarID
        AND (  ( FromDay = :curDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= :time         AND TillTimeOfDay >  :time )
            OR ( FromDay = :curDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= :time )
            OR ( FromDay = :prvDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND TillTimeOfDay >  :time )
        );
```

Comment: i wasnt even aware of that, so thank you. However, i'm still getting the error with the variables. 

syntax error line 4 at position 8 unexpected 'time'.
syntax error line 4 at position 24 unexpected ':'. (line 4)

Comment: there is also the problem you have used the PROCEDURE form, but called it a function. And I suspect you will try use this in a correlated sub-query, and that will explode also, so just writing this as UDTF that returns results for "all things" and then you can join to that safely.

Comment: ah. you're right. how would you modify this into a function? i'm a little lost on that part

Comment: if you are going to use the SQL `select func(t.col_a, t.colb) from table as t` then this most likely will not work. it would be better to turn the two blocks into a single result with all `t.col_a` and `t.col_b` values as the join value, and use a UDTF and perhaps pass an extra set of clauses, if you have some details you can filter on.

Comment: ah. i'm still al little confused. is there anyway you can format the above into some sort of pseudo code? i'm confused on the tables...

Comment: that makes sense, I am somewhat trying to avoid having to write this all into a "blog post" sized answer...

Comment: is there another way you can write it somwhere and link it? I posted this on reddit as well. https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/ye8qoz/im_getting_a_syntax_error_when_trying_to_create/

Comment: i think the "time" variable is tripping it up. 

DECLARE
        time time TIME(:dateTime);
     curDay  int;
     prvDay  int;
        shiftID int;

i keep getting "Syntax error: unexpected 'TIME'. (line 8)"