# How to conver this SQL server Function into a CTE in snowflake

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I have two functions in SQL server that i'm trying to recreate in snowflake. i want to make it a CTE instead as i'm having many issues with it being a function (very picky about date parameters passed through)

I'm not quite thinking of it in the right way. So we pass two paramters through, a date and an int. and the function returns an INT value for us. I'm kind of "stuck".

```
--Function 1: Straight from SQL server
ALTER   FUNCTION [dbo].[cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime] (
       @dateTime datetime,
       @shiftCalendarID int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @time    time = CONVERT( time, @dateTime ),
        @curDay  int,
        @prvDay  int,
        @shiftID int;

    SELECT TOP 1
        @shiftCalendarID = ID,
        @curDay = DATEDIFF( dd, BeginDate, @dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1,
        @prvDay = ( @curDay + PeriodInDays - 2 )       % PeriodInDays + 1
    FROM ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = @shiftCalendarID
        OR (    @shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= @dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC;

    SELECT @shiftID = ID
    FROM Shift
    WHERE ShiftCalendarID = @shiftCalendarID
        AND (  ( FromDay = @curDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= @time         AND TillTimeOfDay >  @time )
            OR ( FromDay = @curDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= @time )
            OR ( FromDay = @prvDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND TillTimeOfDay >  @time )
        );

    RETURN @shiftID;
END 

--GO
```

I had help from a user writing this and was able to get this function written in snowflake and seems to be working properly. here it is below

```
--Function 1 -- Snowflake syntax, currently working
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_AAR.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime (dateTime TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), shiftCalendarID int)

RETURNS table (shiftID int)
AS
$$
WITH T0 (ShiftCalendarID, CurDay, PrvDay)
AS (
    SELECT TOP 1
        ID AS ShiftCalendarID,
        DATEDIFF( day, BeginDate, dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1 AS CurDay,
        ( CurDay + PeriodInDays - 2 ) % PeriodInDays + 1 AS PrvDay
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = shiftCalendarID
        OR (    shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC
),
T1 (TimeValue)
AS (
    SELECT TIME_FROM_PARTS(
        EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM dateTime),
        EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM dateTime),
        EXTRACT(SECOND FROM dateTime))
    )

SELECT ID as shiftID
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.Shift, T0, T1
    WHERE Shift.ShiftCalendarID = T0.ShiftCalendarID
    AND (  ( FromDay = T0.CurDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= T1.TimeValue AND TillTimeOfDay >  T1.TimeValue )
            OR ( FromDay = T0.CurDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= T1.TimeValue )
            OR ( FromDay = T0.PrvDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND TillTimeOfDay >  T1.TimeValue )
        )
$$
;
```

here is function 2:

```
--Function 2: Straight from SQL server
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID] ( @equipmentID int, @date datetime )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    IF @date IS NULL  SET @date = GETDATE();

    DECLARE
        @shiftCalendarID    int,
        @endDate            date;

    WITH cte ( ID, ParentEquipmentID, ShiftCalendarEntityNumber ) AS (
        SELECT ID, ParentEquipmentID, ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM Equipment
        WHERE ID = @equipmentID
    UNION ALL
        SELECT p.ID, p.ParentEquipmentID, p.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM cte
        INNER JOIN Equipment p ON p.ID = cte.ParentEquipmentID AND cte.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber IS NULL
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 @shiftCalendarID = sc.ID, @endDate = sc.EndDate
    FROM cte
    INNER JOIN ShiftCalendar sc ON sc.EntityNumber = cte.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
    WHERE sc.BeginDate <= @date
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate > @date THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,  -- Prio on date range
        sc.BeginDate DESC;

    IF @shiftCalendarID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Default to the last created calendar we find that started before the given time
        SELECT TOP 1 @shiftCalendarID = ID
        FROM ShiftCalendar
        WHERE BeginDate < @date
        ORDER BY BeginDate DESC;
    END;

    RETURN @shiftCalendarID;  -- CASE WHEN @endDate IS NULL OR @endDate > @date THEN @shiftCalendarID END;  -- Return NULL when no matching date range found?

END
GO
```

This one I was able to rewrite in snowflake but the if statement isnt working. I am not sure if snowflake function can use an if statement.

```
ALTER   FUNCTION [dbo].[cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime] (
       @dateTime datetime,
       @shiftCalendarID int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @time    time = CONVERT( time, @dateTime ),
        @curDay  int,
        @prvDay  int,
        @shiftID int;

    SELECT TOP 1
        @shiftCalendarID = ID,
        @curDay = DATEDIFF( dd, BeginDate, @dateTime ) % PeriodInDays + 1,
        @prvDay = ( @curDay + PeriodInDays - 2 )       % PeriodInDays + 1
    FROM ShiftCalendar
    WHERE ID = @shiftCalendarID
        OR (    @shiftCalendarID IS NULL
            AND Name = 'Factory'
            AND BeginDate <= @dateTime )
    ORDER BY BeginDate DESC;

    SELECT @shiftID = ID
    FROM Shift
    WHERE ShiftCalendarID = @shiftCalendarID
        AND (  ( FromDay = @curDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= @time         AND TillTimeOfDay >  @time )
            OR ( FromDay = @curDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND FromTimeOfDay <= @time )
            OR ( FromDay = @prvDay AND FromTimeOfDay >= TillTimeOfDay AND TillTimeOfDay >  @time )
        );

    RETURN @shiftID;
END 

--GO
```

so how are these functions used? i have a view which i was able to recreate in snowflake, but is missing the part that calls the function.

```
ALTER   VIEW [proj].[pvw_PowerBI_ActualUnits]

SELECT 
    e.Name AS ProductionUnit,
    temp.DateTime AS DateTime,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    CONVERT(TIME, temp.DateTime) AS Time,
    CONVERT(DATE, temp.DateTime - ISNULL((SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DateTime) FROM [Shift] s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID), CAST('6:00' AS DateTime))) AS ProductionDate,
    'Actual Units' AS ScrapReason,
    temp.ScrapQuantity AS ScrapQuantity,
    'Auto Registered' AS RegistrationType,
    s.ID
FROM
    (SELECT
        vl.EquipmentID AS ProductionUnit,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, vl.BeginTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, vl.BeginTime), 0)) AS DateTime,
        SUM(vl.Quantity) AS ScrapQuantity
    FROM oee.ValueLog vl WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN KPIInstance ki ON ki.ID = vl.KPIInstanceID AND ki.KPIDefinitionID LIKE 'COUNT-OUT:%'
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, vl.BeginTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, vl.BeginTime), 0)), vl.EquipmentID) temp
INNER JOIN Equipment e ON e.ID = temp.ProductionUnit
INNER JOIN Shift s ON s.ID = dbo.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime(temp.DateTime, dbo.cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID(temp.ProductionUnit, temp.DateTime)) -- here is where the functions are called
```

i was able to rewrite this in snowflake for the most part minus calling the function.

```
SELECT 
    e.Name AS ProductionUnit,
    temp.DateTime AS DateTime,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    temp.DateTime::TIME AS Time,
    --CONVERT(DATE, temp.DateTime - ISNULL((SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DateTime) FROM [Shift] s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID), CAST('6:00' AS DateTime))) AS ProductionDate,
    
    IFNULL(dateadd(HOUR, - (HOUR(SELECT MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay)
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.Shift s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID)), temp.DateTime), (dateadd(HOUR, - 6, temp.DateTime))) AS ProductionDate ,
    
    'Actual Units' AS ScrapReason,
    temp.ScrapQuantity AS ScrapQuantity,
    'Auto Registered' AS RegistrationType
FROM
    (SELECT
        vl.EquipmentID AS ProductionUnit,
        DATEADD(MIN, 30 * (DATE_PART(MINUTE, vl.BeginTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, '0', vl.BeginTime), '0')) AS DateTime,
        SUM(vl.Quantity) AS ScrapQuantity
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.ValueLog vl 
    INNER JOIN KPIInstance ki ON ki.ID = vl.KPIInstanceID AND ki.KPIDefinitionID LIKE 'COUNT-OUT:%'
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MIN, 30 * (DATE_PART(MINUTE, vl.BeginTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, '0', vl.BeginTime), '0')), vl.EquipmentID) as temp, shiftcalendar_cte, RAW_CPMS_AAR.Equipment e, RAW_CPMS_AAR.Shift s
    WHERE e.ID = temp.ProductionUnit
```

Now i dont know if there is a better way to do this, maybe a cte is better. i know functions are not resource friendly, i'm simply trying to recreate this. open to any ideas or help.

Comment: It accepts some parameters, a recursive CTE, has IF conditions, and you want to write it as CTE. So you will convert this function to one SQL? Can you share your work?

Comment: @GokhanAtil i updated with my attempt to convert to CTE. it's not doing the same thing as the function, obviously my CTE is wrong and missing things. but cant wrap my head around the logic. The input parameters i can put in the where clause of the SQl i'm using. meaning i can see where shiftCalendarid='myinput', etc. ... i'm heading in the right direction i think but quite far from the finish line and need some direction. Another option is to convert the CTE to a function in snowflake... which i'm open to

Comment: so here we are two and half weeks after you first asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74214082/im-getting-a-syntax-error-when-trying-to-create-this-function-in-snowflake and you seem to have made zero progress.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim you're obviously very skilled at SQL and i can respect that. it's Sunday and I'm sitting here trying to continue to learn and work on this. I've been on my computer for the last 6+ hours looking and trying to figure this out.  i have about 10 worksheets each with different variations of code, and i cant figure this out. It's frustrating but I'm slowly making progress. If you can help, please help. Otherwise please leave me alone.

if you care, i updated with what I've done. i don't update if there's no progress. i'll continue to ask because that's what the community is for.

Comment: my point which was not said well was, "the way you are asking the question is not getting traction, perhaps break it into smaller questions". To that end there is a function, but of almost more importance than the function is how is the function is being used. Because Snowflake is a little less friendly towards usages that are performance poor. Which is to say, it does not support chunks of correlated sub-queries, which appears to be how you most likely will use this.  This point I noted in an answer on an earlier question. But to really help the "how will this be used" data/ and queries...

Comment: .. are super important. Sometimes a UDTF makes more sense, sometimes a CTE.. But these question do not have that context, and just ask "help me translate this" but what you are stuck on is not clear, the code you have posted today, is more or less the cut'n'paste of prior answers, so and yet you have not explained the problems..

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim that makes sense! i'm not kidding when i say i've been here for 6+ hours and am getting frustrated. so i apologize. so to answer your question "how will this be sued?" i have a view with a where clause that does a join on an id that's returned from the function. i have a suspicion i can simply create a where clause that returns what i'm using. but i'm not knowledgeable enough to make that call. like i mentioned i have a few views that live in sql server but would like to have available to me in snowflake. in the views (3), they call on this function one way or another....

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim i will update the post to give a bit more color

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim i updated the post. it may not may not make sense. i feel like i don't know if i'm asking the right questions. i came to stackoverflow simply because it's a big community and figured someone might be able to point me in the right direction. i will admit this is a fun project and i am learning quite a bit about snowflake.

Comment: `INNER JOIN Shift s ON s.ID = dbo.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime(temp.DateTime, dbo.cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID(temp.ProductionUnit, temp.DateTime)) -- here is where the functions are called` this is honestly, very helpful...

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim lol. i'm not sure if that's sarcasm or not. most of the comments in there are for myself.

Comment: sorry, I should have removed the embedded comment, but that whole line, does show how you are using the function, and the is VERY helpful, even the comment, "this is where I am stuck" is helpful. But I can see how my comment could come across poorly.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim haha. that's the problem with text, there's no context. commenting where i'm having issues is how I found it helpful to understand what's going on. i went through every line of code to make sure i can explain what's being done and how it impacts the rest of the code. in all honesty, this exercise is giving me a bit of everything.  i do understand the function and what's its doing. articulating the logic and rewriting the code is what i'm having trouble with.

Comment: FYI, the "second function" work in progress rewrite, is actually the first function T-SQL version.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim sorry i replied to the wrong comment.

Answer (score 0):

ok, some small translations:

```
DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, vl.BeginTime), 0)
```

is truncating to the hour, so is the same as

```
date_trunc('HOUR', vl.BeginTime)
```

that `dateadd` thus is:

```
select column1 
    ,date_trunc('hour', column1) as t_hour
    ,truncate(minute(column1)/30)*30
    ,timeadd('minute', truncate(minute(column1)/30)*30, date_trunc('hour', column1)) as datetime
from values 
    ('2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz),
    ('2022-11-14 12:34:01'::timestamp_ntz);
```

| COLUMN1 | T_HOUR | TRUNCATE(MINUTE(COLUMN1)/30)*30 | DATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-14 13:26:01.000 | 2022-11-14 13:00:00.000 | 0 | 2022-11-14 13:00:00.000 |
| 2022-11-14 12:34:01.000 | 2022-11-14 12:00:00.000 | 30 | 2022-11-14 12:30:00.000 |

So moving that sub-select that you alias as `temp` into a CTE, and get that "working"

```
WITH table_oee_valuelog(equipmentid, begintime, quantity, kpiinstanceid) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 10, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 11, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 12, 100)
), table_kpiinstance(id, kpidefinitionid) as (
    select * from values
    (100, 'COUNT-OUT:extra stuff')
)--, temp_sub_select as (
    SELECT
        vl.equipmentid as productionunit,
        timeadd('minute', truncate(minute(vl.BeginTime)/30)*30, date_trunc('hour', vl.BeginTime)) as datetime,
        SUM(vl.quantity) AS scrapquantity
    FROM table_oee_valuelog as vl
    INNER JOIN table_kpiinstance as ki 
        ON ki.ID = vl.KPIInstanceID 
            AND ki.KPIDefinitionID LIKE 'COUNT-OUT:%'
    GROUP BY 1,2
;)
```

| PRODUCTIONUNIT | DATETIME | SCRAPQUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-14 13:00:00.000 | 21 |
| 1 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 12 |

### implementing cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID

so if we extend our table data a bit more we can take a first crack at `cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID` like:

```
WITH table_oee_valuelog(equipmentid, begintime, quantity, kpiinstanceid) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 10, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 11, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 12, 100)
), table_kpiinstance(id, kpidefinitionid) as (
    select * from values
    (100, 'COUNT-OUT:extra stuff')
), table_equipment(id, name, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) as (
    select * from values
    (1,'equipment one', 2, null),
    (2,'equipment two', null, 80),
    (3,'equipment three', 4, 81),
    (4,'equipment four', null, 82)
), table_shift(id, shiftcalendarid, reference) as (
    select * from values
    (1001,  9001, 'a')
), table_shiftcalendar(id, entitynumber, begindate, enddate) as (
    select * from values
    (699, 80, '2021-01-01'::date, '2021-12-31'::date),
    (700, 80, '2022-01-01'::date, '2022-12-31'::date),
    --(701, 81, '2022-02-01'::date, '2022-11-30'::date),
    (702, 82, '2022-10-01'::date, '2022-11-15'::date)

), cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID/*(id, shiftCalendarID)*/ as (
    with recursive rec_cte (id, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) as (
    
        select 
            ID, 
            ParentEquipmentID, 
            ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM table_equipment
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT 
            r.ID, 
            p.ParentEquipmentID, 
            p.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM rec_cte as r
        INNER JOIN table_equipment p 
            ON p.ID = r.ParentEquipmentID 
                AND r.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber IS NULL
    )
    select * from rec_cte as c
    left join table_shiftcalendar as sc
        on sc.entitynumber = c.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
    where shiftcalendarentitynumber is not null
    qualify row_number() over (partition by c.id order by sc.begindate desc ) = 1
)
select * from cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID;
```

This is missing the `@date` based filters and the catch all, as to product the "latest" all bit of equipment, cannot be done yet.

| ID | PARENTEQUIPMENTID | SHIFTCALENDARENTITYNUMBER | ID_2 | ENTITYNUMBER | BEGINDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 80 | 700 | 80 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2 |  | 80 | 700 | 80 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 3 | 4 | 81 |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  | 82 | 702 | 82 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-11-15 |

so we need to weave this current data, with the `temp` table, how convenient we made it a CTE already...

so the next partial step is:

```
WITH table_oee_valuelog(equipmentid, begintime, quantity, kpiinstanceid) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 10, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 11, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 12, 100),
    (2, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 20, 100),
    (3, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 30, 100),
    (4, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 44, 100)   
), table_kpiinstance(id, kpidefinitionid) as (
    select * from values
    (100, 'COUNT-OUT:extra stuff')
), table_equipment(id, name, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) as (
    select * from values
    (1,'equipment one', 2, null),
    (2,'equipment two', null, 80),
    (3,'equipment three', 4, 81),
    (4,'equipment four', null, 82)
), table_shift(id, shiftcalendarid, reference) as (
    select * from values
    (1001,  9001, 'a')
), table_shiftcalendar(id, entitynumber, begindate, enddate) as (
    select * from values
    (699, 80, '2021-01-01'::date, '2021-12-31'::date),
    (700, 80, '2022-01-01'::date, '2022-12-31'::date),
    (701, 80, '2023-01-01'::date, '2023-12-31'::date),
    --(701, 81, '2022-02-01'::date, '2022-11-30'::date),
    (702, 82, '2022-10-01'::date, '2022-11-15'::date)
), temp_sub_select as (
    SELECT
        vl.equipmentid as productionunit,
        timeadd('minute', truncate(minute(vl.BeginTime)/30)*30, date_trunc('hour', vl.BeginTime)) as datetime,
        SUM(vl.quantity) AS scrapquantity
    FROM table_oee_valuelog as vl
    INNER JOIN table_kpiinstance as ki 
        ON ki.ID = vl.KPIInstanceID 
            AND ki.KPIDefinitionID LIKE 'COUNT-OUT:%'
    GROUP BY 1,2   
), cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a/*(id, shiftCalendarID)*/ as (
    with recursive rec_cte (id, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) as (
    
        select 
            ID, 
            ParentEquipmentID, 
            ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM table_equipment
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT 
            r.ID, 
            p.ParentEquipmentID, 
            p.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM rec_cte as r
        INNER JOIN table_equipment p 
            ON p.ID = r.ParentEquipmentID 
                AND r.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber IS NULL
    )
    select 
        c.id, 
        sc.id as shiftCalendarID, 
        sc.begindate, sc.enddate
    from rec_cte as c
    left join table_shiftcalendar as sc
        on sc.entitynumber = c.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
    where shiftcalendarentitynumber is not null
)--, last_calendar_per_equipment as (
    
    select *
        ,iff(c.enddate is null or c.enddate > t.datetime, 1, 2) as order_a
        ,row_number() over (partition by t.productionunit, t.datetime order by order_a, c.begindate desc) as rn
    from temp_sub_select as t
    left join cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a as c
        on t.productionunit = c.id 
            and c.begindate <= t.datetime 
;)
```

this gives:

| PRODUCTIONUNIT | DATETIME | SCRAPQUANTITY | ID | SHIFTCALENDARID | BEGINDATE | ENDDATE | ORDER_A | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-14 13:00:00.000 | 21 | 1 | 700 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-11-14 13:00:00.000 | 21 | 1 | 699 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 12 | 1 | 700 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 12 | 1 | 699 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 20 | 2 | 700 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 20 | 2 | 699 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 30 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 44 | 4 | 702 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-11-15 | 1 | 1 |

last step of this function can be handled with this CTE which we can join to the prior results, and take if the prior results are null.

```
   select 
        t.datetime,
        sc.id
    from (
        select distinct datetime
        from temp_sub_select
    ) as t
    join table_shiftcalendar as sc
        on sc.begindate <= t.datetime 
    qualify row_number() over (partition by t.datetime order by sc.begindate desc) = 1
```

weave those together and a little data change:

```
WITH table_oee_valuelog(equipmentid, begintime, quantity, kpiinstanceid) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 10, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 11, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 12, 100),
    (2, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 20, 100),
    (3, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 30, 100),
    (4, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 44, 100)   
), table_kpiinstance(id, kpidefinitionid) as (
    select * from values
    (100, 'COUNT-OUT:extra stuff')
), table_equipment(id, name, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) as (
    select * from values
    (1,'equipment one', 2, null),
    (2,'equipment two', null, 80),
    (3,'equipment three', 4, 81),
    (4,'equipment four', null, 82)
), table_shift(id, shiftcalendarid, reference) as (
    select * from values
    (1001,  9001, 'a')
), table_shiftcalendar(id, entitynumber, begindate, enddate) as (
    select * from values
    (699, 80, '2021-01-01'::date, '2021-12-31'::date),
    (700, 80, '2022-01-01'::date, '2022-12-31'::date),
    (701, 80, '2023-01-01'::date, '2023-12-31'::date),
    --(701, 81, '2022-02-01'::date, '2022-11-30'::date),
    (702, 82, '2022-10-01'::date, '2022-11-15'::date),
    (703, 89, '2022-11-01'::date, '2022-11-15'::date)
), temp_sub_select as (
    SELECT
        vl.equipmentid as productionunit,
        timeadd('minute', truncate(minute(vl.BeginTime)/30)*30, date_trunc('hour', vl.BeginTime)) as datetime,
        SUM(vl.quantity) AS scrapquantity
    FROM table_oee_valuelog as vl
    INNER JOIN table_kpiinstance as ki 
        ON ki.ID = vl.KPIInstanceID 
            AND ki.KPIDefinitionID LIKE 'COUNT-OUT:%'
    GROUP BY 1,2   
), cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a/*(id, shiftCalendarID)*/ as (
    with recursive rec_cte (id, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) as (
    
        select 
            ID, 
            ParentEquipmentID, 
            ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM table_equipment
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT 
            r.ID, 
            p.ParentEquipmentID, 
            p.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM rec_cte as r
        INNER JOIN table_equipment p 
            ON p.ID = r.ParentEquipmentID 
                AND r.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber IS NULL
    )
    select 
        c.id, 
        sc.id as shiftCalendarID, 
        sc.begindate, sc.enddate
    from rec_cte as c
    left join table_shiftcalendar as sc
        on sc.entitynumber = c.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
    where shiftcalendarentitynumber is not null
), cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_b as (
    
    select t.productionunit, 
        t.org_datetime,
        t.datetime,
        c.shiftCalendarID
    from (
        select
            productionunit,
            datetime as org_datetime,
            nvl(datetime, CURRENT_DATE) as datetime /* handle the null case from the T-SQL */
        from temp_sub_select
    ) as t
    left join cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a as c
        on t.productionunit = c.id 
            and c.begindate <= t.datetime 
    qualify row_number() over (partition by t.productionunit, t.datetime 
                               order by iff(c.enddate is null or c.enddate > t.datetime, 1, 2), c.begindate desc) = 1
), max_shiftCalendar_per_datetime as (
    select 
        t.datetime,
        sc.id
    from (
        select distinct nvl(datetime, CURRENT_DATE) as datetime
        from temp_sub_select
    ) as t
    join table_shiftcalendar as sc
        on sc.begindate <= t.datetime 
    qualify row_number() over (partition by t.datetime order by sc.begindate desc) = 1
)--, last_calendar_per_equipment as (
    select 
        a.productionunit
        ,a.org_datetime
        ,a.shiftCalendarID, b.id
        ,nvl(a.shiftCalendarID, b.id) as shiftCalendarID
    from cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_b as a
    join max_shiftCalendar_per_datetime as b
        on a.datetime = b.datetime
;)
```

gives:

| PRODUCTIONUNIT | ORG_DATETIME | SHIFTCALENDARID | ID | SHIFTCALENDARID_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-14 13:00:00.000 | 700 | 703 | 700 |
| 1 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 700 | 703 | 700 |
| 2 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 700 | 703 | 700 |
| 3 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 |  | 703 | 703 |
| 4 | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | 702 | 703 | 702 |

### Mostly Complete answer:

So I striped `ProductionDate` and the two fixed string from my answer but:

```
--CREATE VIEW proj.pvw_PowerBI_ActualUnits
WITH table_oee_valuelog(equipmentid, begintime, quantity, kpiinstanceid) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 10, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:26:01'::timestamp_ntz, 11, 100),
    (1, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 12, 100),
    (2, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 20, 100),
    (3, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 30, 100),
    (4, '2022-11-14 13:34:01'::timestamp_ntz, 44, 100)   
), table_kpiinstance(id, kpidefinitionid) as (
    select * from values
    (100, 'COUNT-OUT:extra stuff')
), table_equipment(id, name, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) as (
    select * from values
    (1,'equipment one', 2, null),
    (2,'equipment two', null, 80),
    (3,'equipment three', 4, 81),
    (4,'equipment four', null, 82)
), table_shift(id, shiftcalendarid, reference, FromDay, FromTimeOfDay, TillTimeOfDay) as (
    select * from values
    (1001,  700, 'a', 8, '06:00'::time,'18:00'::time),
    (1001,  702, 'a', 5, '06:00'::time,'18:00'::time),
    (1001,  703, 'a', 4, '06:00'::time,'18:00'::time)
), table_shiftcalendar(id, entitynumber, begindate, enddate, name, PeriodInDays) as (
    select * from values
    (699, 80, '2021-01-01'::date, '2021-12-31'::date, 'Factory', 10),
    (700, 80, '2022-01-01'::date, '2022-12-31'::date, 'Factory', 10),
    (701, 80, '2023-01-01'::date, '2023-12-31'::date, 'Factory', 10),
    --(701, 81, '2022-02-01'::date, '2022-11-30'::date, 'Factory', 10),
    (702, 82, '2022-10-01'::date, '2022-11-15'::date, 'Factory', 10),
    (703, 89, '2022-11-01'::date, '2022-11-15'::date, 'Factory', 10)
), temp_sub_select as (
    SELECT
        vl.equipmentid as productionunit,
        timeadd('minute', truncate(minute(vl.BeginTime)/30)*30, date_trunc('hour', vl.BeginTime)) as datetime,
        SUM(vl.quantity) AS scrapquantity
    FROM table_oee_valuelog as vl
    INNER JOIN table_kpiinstance as ki 
        ON ki.ID = vl.KPIInstanceID 
            AND ki.KPIDefinitionID LIKE 'COUNT-OUT:%'
    GROUP BY 1,2   
), cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a as (
    with recursive rec_cte (id, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) as (
    
        select 
            ID, 
            ParentEquipmentID, 
            ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM table_equipment
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT 
            r.ID, 
            p.ParentEquipmentID, 
            p.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
        FROM rec_cte as r
        INNER JOIN table_equipment p 
            ON p.ID = r.ParentEquipmentID 
                AND r.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber IS NULL
    )
    select 
        c.id, 
        sc.id as shiftCalendarID, 
        sc.begindate, sc.enddate
    from rec_cte as c
    left join table_shiftcalendar as sc
        on sc.entitynumber = c.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
    where shiftcalendarentitynumber is not null
), cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_b as (
    
    select t.productionunit, 
        t.org_datetime,
        t.datetime,
        c.shiftCalendarID
    from (
        select
            productionunit,
            datetime as org_datetime,
            nvl(datetime, CURRENT_DATE) as datetime /* handle the null case from the T-SQL */
        from temp_sub_select
    ) as t
    left join cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a as c
        on t.productionunit = c.id 
            and c.begindate <= t.datetime 
    qualify row_number() over (partition by t.productionunit, t.datetime 
                               order by iff(c.enddate is null or c.enddate > t.datetime, 1, 2), c.begindate desc) = 1
), max_shiftCalendar_per_datetime as (
    select 
        t.datetime,
        sc.id
    from (
        select distinct nvl(datetime, CURRENT_DATE) as datetime
        from temp_sub_select
    ) as t
    join table_shiftcalendar as sc
        on sc.begindate <= t.datetime 
    qualify row_number() over (partition by t.datetime order by sc.begindate desc) = 1
), last_calendar_per_equipment as (
    select 
        a.productionunit
        ,a.org_datetime
        ,nvl(a.shiftCalendarID, b.id) as shiftCalendarID
    from cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_b as a
    join max_shiftCalendar_per_datetime as b
        on a.datetime = b.datetime
), cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime as (
    with t0 as (
        select 
            x.productionunit
            ,x.org_datetime
            ,x.org_datetime::time as org_time
            ,x.ShiftCalendarID
            ,DATEDIFF( day, BeginDate, x.org_datetime ) % PeriodInDays + 1 AS CurDay
            ,( CurDay + PeriodInDays - 2 ) % PeriodInDays + 1 AS PrvDay
        from last_calendar_per_equipment as x
        join table_shiftcalendar as sc
        where sc.id = x.shiftCalendarID
            OR ( x.shiftCalendarID IS NULL
                AND sc.Name = 'Factory'
                AND sc.BeginDate <= x.org_datetime )
        QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by x.productionunit, x.org_datetime order by sc.begindate desc) = 1
    )
    SELECT
        s.id
        ,s.reference
        ,productionunit
        ,org_datetime
    ,s.ShiftCalendarID
    ,s.FromDay, s.FromTimeOfDay, s.TillTimeOfDay,  T0.CurDay, t0.org_time
    FROM table_shift as s, T0
    WHERE s.ShiftCalendarID = T0.ShiftCalendarID
    AND (  ( s.FromDay = T0.CurDay AND s.FromTimeOfDay <= t0.org_time AND s.TillTimeOfDay >  t0.org_time )
            OR ( s.FromDay = T0.CurDay AND s.FromTimeOfDay >= s.TillTimeOfDay AND s.FromTimeOfDay <= t0.org_time )
        OR ( s.FromDay = T0.PrvDay AND s.FromTimeOfDay >= s.TillTimeOfDay AND s.TillTimeOfDay >  t0.org_time )
        )
)
SELECT 
    e.name AS productionunit,
    temp.datetime AS datetime,
    s.reference AS shift,
    temp.DateTime::time AS Time,
    temp.ScrapQuantity AS ScrapQuantity,
    s.ID
FROM temp_sub_select as temp
INNER JOIN table_equipment e 
    ON e.ID = temp.ProductionUnit
INNER JOIN cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime s 
    ON s.productionunit = temp.ProductionUnit 
        and  temp.datetime = s.org_datetime
```

as far as I can follow, does what your functions do, and unrolls the correlated query, as that would never work in Snowflake.

| PRODUCTIONUNIT | DATETIME | SHIFT | TIME | SCRAPQUANTITY | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| equipment one | 2022-11-14 13:00:00.000 | a | 13:00:00 | 21 | 1001 |
| equipment one | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | a | 13:30:00 | 12 | 1001 |
| equipment two | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | a | 13:30:00 | 20 | 1001 |
| equipment three | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | a | 13:30:00 | 30 | 1001 |
| equipment four | 2022-11-14 13:30:00.000 | a | 13:30:00 | 44 | 1001 |

Not so bad for five hours work...

Comment: I appreciate this and the explanations are pretty good - I'll get to this when I get off work in a little. But i have a general question. What is the process for going about solving something like this, i know you said break it into smaller parts that can be solved. But what is the overall process. meaning do i start with the functions and rewrite those? and within the functions do i try to rewrite the end statement that puts everything together and "work my way out". I'm trying to build and understand the process.

Comment: hmm, the explanation is poor, as far as I am concerned, as it was taking so long to write/debug the SQL. What is the process, the answer reads in the order of exactly how I went about rewriting the functions, and each steps SQL is showing the process of unfolding the functions and their interaction with the wider data, and the assumptions of the nature and layout of the data.. maybe it would be better to say, I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: your query looked complicated but fairly straight forward. I figured the best way for me to try was to recreate what you had using a different view -- it seems you did most of the heavy lifting. but there is a portion that does not return any results but i expect it to. not quite sure what i'm doing wrong. i created another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74608202/converting-sql-view-that-uses-functions-to-work-in-snowflake