# Converting SQL view that uses functions to work in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I have a view in SQL server that i'm trying to convert to work in snowflake. The view uses two functions within it that are called to join onto another table.

I'm following steps provided by another user, but i'm getting lost somewhere in the middle and feel a little stuck.

Here is the query for the SQL Server view:

```
ALTER VIEW [proj].[pvw_PowerBI_ScrapList]
AS
SELECT
    e.Name AS ProductionUnit,
    temp.DateTime AS DateTime,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    CONVERT(TIME, temp.DateTime) AS Time,
    CONVERT(DATE, temp.DateTime - ISNULL((SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DateTime) FROM Shift s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID), CAST('6:00' AS DateTime))) AS ProductionDate,
    temp.ScrapReason AS ScrapReason,
    temp.Quantity AS ScrapQuantity,
    'Manually Registered' AS RegistrationType
FROM (SELECT 
        CAST(SUM(sreg.ScrapQuantity) AS int) AS Quantity,
        sreas.Name As ScrapReason,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, sreg.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, sreg.ScrapTime), 0)) AS DateTime,
        srer.EquipmentID AS EquipmentID
    FROM qms.ScrapRegistration sreg WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN qms.ScrapReason sreas WITH (NOLOCK) ON sreas.ID = sreg.ScrapReasonID -- creating CTE of this table 
    INNER JOIN WorkRequest wr WITH (NOLOCK) ON wr.ID = sreg.WorkRequestID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
    INNER JOIN SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement srer WITH (NOLOCK) ON srer.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, sreg.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, sreg.ScrapTime), 0)), srer.EquipmentID, sreas.Name) temp
INNER JOIN Equipment e WITH (NOLOCK) ON e.ID = temp.EquipmentID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
INNER JOIN ShiftCalendar sc WITH (NOLOCK) ON sc.ID = dbo.cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID(e.ID, temp.DateTime) -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
INNER JOIN Shift s WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.ID = dbo.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime(temp.DateTime, sc.ID)  -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
UNION
SELECT
    e.Name AS ProductionUnit,
    temp.DateTime AS DateTime,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    CONVERT(TIME, temp.DateTime) AS Time,
    CONVERT(DATE, temp.DateTime - ISNULL((SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DateTime) FROM Shift s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID), CAST('6:00' AS DateTime))) AS ProductionDate,
    temp.ScrapReason AS ScrapReason,
    temp.Quantity AS ScrapQuantity,
    'Auto Registered' AS RegistrationType
FROM (SELECT
        SUM(ISNULL(asr.ScrapQuantity, 0)) AS Quantity,
        sreas.Name As ScrapReason,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, asr.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, asr.ScrapTime), 0)) AS DateTime,
        srer.EquipmentID AS EquipmentID
    FROM proj.AutoScrapRegistration asr WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN qms.ScrapReason sreas WITH (NOLOCK) ON sreas.ID = asr.ScrapReasonID
    INNER JOIN WorkRequest wr WITH (NOLOCK) ON wr.ID = asr.WorkRequestID
    INNER JOIN SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement srer WITH (NOLOCK) ON srer.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, asr.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, asr.ScrapTime), 0)), srer.EquipmentID, sreas.Name) temp
INNER JOIN Equipment e WITH (NOLOCK) ON e.ID = temp.EquipmentID
INNER JOIN ShiftCalendar sc WITH (NOLOCK) ON sc.ID = dbo.cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID(temp.EquipmentID, temp.DateTime) -- the function is called here
INNER JOIN Shift s WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.ID = dbo.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime(temp.DateTime, sc.ID) -- the function is called here
```

i'm ignoring the union for now to try and get something simply working.

The functions are highlighted in this post [How to conver this SQL server Function into a CTE in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74413154/how-to-conver-this-sql-server-function-into-a-cte-in-snowflake?noredirect=1#comment131409301_74413154)

Here is what i have so far:

```
WITH table_ScrapRegistration (
    Quantity
    ,ScrapReason
    ,DATETIME
    ,EquipmentID
    ,ScrapReasonID
    ,WorkRequestID
    ,SegmentRequirementID
    )
AS (
    SELECT CAST(SUM(sreg.ScrapQuantity) AS INT) AS Quantity
        ,sreas.Name AS ScrapReason
        ,DATEADD(MIN, 30 * (DATE_PART(MINUTE, sreg.ScrapTime) / 30)::INT, date_trunc('HOUR', sreg.ScrapTime)) AS DATETIME
        ,srer.EquipmentID AS EquipmentID
        ,sreas.ID AS ScrapReasonID
        ,wr.ID AS WorkRequestID
        ,srer.SegmentRequirementID AS SegmentRequirementID
    FROM DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.ScrapRegistration sreg
    INNER JOIN DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.ScrapReason sreas ON sreas.ID = sreg.ScrapReasonID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
    INNER JOIN DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.WorkRequest wr ON wr.ID = sreg.WorkRequestID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
    INNER JOIN DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement srer ON srer.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MIN, 30 * (DATE_PART(MINUTE, sreg.ScrapTime) / 30)::INT, date_trunc('HOUR', sreg.ScrapTime))
        ,srer.EquipmentID
        ,sreas.Name
        ,sreas.ID
        ,wr.ID
        ,srer.SegmentRequirementID
    )
    ,table_scrapreason (
    name
    ,ID
    )
AS (
    SELECT name
        ,ID
    FROM DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.ScrapReason
    )
    ,table_workrequest (
    ID
    ,SegmentRequirementID
    ) -- this is from a join)
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,SegmentRequirementID
    FROM DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.WorkRequest
    )
    ,table_SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement (
    EquipmentID
    ,SegmentRequirementID
    )
AS (
    SELECT EquipmentID
        ,SegmentRequirementID
    FROM DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement
    )
    ,table_equipment (
    id
    ,name
    ,ParentEquipmentID
    ,ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
    )
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,name
            ,ParentEquipmentID
    ,ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
    FROM DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.Equipment
    )
    ,table_ShiftCalendar (
    id,
    entitynumber,
    begindate,
    enddate,
    name,
    PeriodInDays
    )
AS (
    SELECT id,
        entitynumber,
        begindate,
        enddate,
        name,
        PeriodInDays
    FROM DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.ShiftCalendar)
    ,table_shift (
    ID
    ,Reference
    ,FromDay
    )
AS -- this is from the temp table
    (
    SELECT ID
        ,Reference
        ,FromDay
    FROM DB_BI_DEV.RAW_CPMS_LAG.shift
    )
    ,temp_sub_select
AS (
    SELECT sreg.Quantity AS Quantity
        ,sreas.name AS ScrapReason
        ,timeadd('minute', TRUNCATE (minute(sreg.DATETIME) / 30) * 30, date_trunc('hour', sreg.DATETIME)) AS DATETIME
        ,srer.EquipmentID AS EquipmentID
    FROM table_ScrapRegistration sreg
    INNER JOIN table_scrapreason sreas ON sreas.ID = sreg.ScrapReasonID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
    INNER JOIN table_workrequest wr ON wr.ID = sreg.WorkRequestID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
    INNER JOIN table_SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement srer ON srer.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID -- CREATE CTE OF THIS TABLE
    GROUP BY sreg.Quantity 
        ,sreas.name 
        ,timeadd('minute', TRUNCATE (minute(sreg.DATETIME) / 30) * 30, date_trunc('hour', sreg.DATETIME))
        ,srer.EquipmentID
    )
        --select * from cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a
        --when i run this i get results
        
    , cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a
    as (
    
    WITH recursive rec_cte(id, parentequipmentid, shiftcalendarentitynumber) AS (
            SELECT ID,
                ParentEquipmentID,
                ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
            FROM table_equipment
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT r.ID,
                p.ParentEquipmentID,
                p.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
            FROM rec_cte AS r
            INNER JOIN table_equipment p ON p.ID = r.ParentEquipmentID
                AND r.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber IS NULL
            )
    SELECT c.id,
        sc.id AS shiftCalendarID,
        sc.begindate,
        sc.enddate
    FROM rec_cte AS c
    LEFT JOIN table_shiftcalendar AS sc ON sc.entitynumber = c.ShiftCalendarEntityNumber
    WHERE shiftcalendarentitynumber IS NOT NULL
    )
    
    select * from cte_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID_part_a
    
    -- when i run this, i dont get any results.
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here - can we simplify to the basics, to make it easier to answer and understand the whole enchilada?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa i was attempting to do that in the recreation. i tried to recreate each table as a separate CTE and then slowly piece it together. What do you mean simplify to the basics? At a basic level, there are a handful of tables that are doing simple joins, the problem i'm having is stitching the function in to get the output i'm seeking.

Comment: If you want help with "stitching the function in to get the output i'm seeking", please give us some sample data and sample results - so we can see the results you are getting now, and the desired results